# A completely positive equivariant map $\varphi: A \to B$ induces a map on the full crossed products

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, discrete-dynamical-systems, crossed-products

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Let $(A,\alpha)$ and $(B,\beta)$ be $G$-$C^*$-algebras and $\varphi: A \to B$ be $G$-equivariant and completely positive. All crossed products in this post are full (= universal).

I want to prove that there is a completely positive map
$$\varphi \rtimes G: A \rtimes_\alpha G \to B \rtimes_\beta G$$
such that $(\varphi\rtimes G)(\sum_s a_s s) = \sum_s \varphi(a_s)s$.

I managed to prove the following using the $G$-equivariant Stinespring theorem:

> Assume that $u: G\to B(H)$ is a unitary representation and $\sigma: A \to B(H)$ a completely positive map satisfying $\sigma(\alpha_g(a)) = u_g \sigma(a)u_g^*$ (i.e. $\sigma$ is $G$-equivariant where $B(H)$ has the $G$-action induced by $u$). Then there is a unique completely positive map
> $$\sigma \rtimes G: A \rtimes G \to B(H)$$
> satisfying $\sigma \rtimes G(\sum_s a_s s) = \sum_s \sigma(a_s)u_s.$

I think I might be able to use this result to prove the result I want: Maybe the following works:

Let $(u,\pi)$ be a covariant representation of $B \rtimes G$ on $H$ where $\pi$ is chosen faithful. Then consider the composition $\sigma: A \to B(H)$ defined by
$$A \stackrel{\varphi}\to B \stackrel{i}\to B \rtimes G \stackrel{\pi}\to B(H)$$
which is completely positive and satisfies $\sigma(\alpha_g(a)) = u_g \sigma(a)u_g^*$. Hence, by the above result, we obtain an induced map
$$\sigma \rtimes G: A \rtimes G \to B(H).$$

If we can check that $(\sigma \rtimes G)(A \rtimes G) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(\pi)$ then we can define
$$\varphi \rtimes G(x) = \pi^{-1}(\sigma \rtimes G)(x) \in B \rtimes G$$
which would yield the desired extension. However, I don't think the above inclusion holds.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thanks!

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA On second thoughts, I think the claim $(\sigma \rtimes G)(A \rtimes G)\subseteq \operatorname{Im}(\pi \circ i)$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for a comment).  Your notation is confusing you, I think.

A *covariant* representation is not really of $B\rtimes G$, but is of the pair $(B,\beta)$.  In particular, $\pi:B\rightarrow B(H)$ (notice the domain!) and not a representation of $B\rtimes G$.  The covariant condition, that $\pi(\beta_t(b)) = u_g \pi(b) u_g^*$, ensures that $\pi$ *extends* to a $*$-representation, say $\tilde\pi: B\rtimes G\rightarrow B(H)$.  (Of course, the point is that *any* $*$-representation of $B\rtimes G$ comes from some pair $(\pi,u)$, and so we can confuse them!)

Thus, in your argument, we *do not expect* that $(\sigma \rtimes G)(A\rtimes G) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(\pi)$ but rather in the image of $\tilde\pi$.

Your argument now seems to be to pick $(\pi,u)$ "universal", so that $\tilde\pi$ will be an isometry, and then show that for this $\pi$ we get that $\sigma\rtimes G$ maps into the image of $\tilde\pi$.  I think this is essentially obvious.  First notice that
$$ \sigma = \tilde\pi \circ i \circ \varphi \implies
\sigma(a) = \pi(\varphi(a)) \quad (a\in A), $$
because by definition $\tilde\pi \circ i = \pi$.  By density, we can consider a finite sum $\sum a_s s \in A\rtimes G$, which has
$$ (\sigma \rtimes G) \Big(\sum a_s s\Big) = \sum \sigma(a_s) s
= \sum \pi(\varphi(a_s)) s, $$
which is clearly a member of the image of $\tilde\pi$.

Comment: But why can we pick $\widetilde{\pi}$ to be an isometry? Is this always possible?

Comment: What's the _definition_ of the "full" crossed product $B\rtimes G$?  For me, it satisfies the universal property given by covariant representations.  You can construct it by, for example, taking the direct sum over (all equivalence classes of not too large in a cardinality sense) covariant reps: this direct sum will then be the "universal" one you seek.

Comment: Also, didn't your original question specify that we could find a faithful such $\tilde\pi$? (which is then an isometry thanks to the metrical natural of $C^*$-algebras).

Comment: Ah yes you can take the direct sum! I didn't realise this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In fact we can simply take the universal GNS-representation of $B \rtimes G.$